# problem in calling javascript function color(this)

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, addeventlistener

why does on calling color(this) e.target value undefined and when i directly call the color function beside of mouseover then it work why?

```js
const colors = [
        "#e74c3c",
        "#8e44ad",
        "#3498db",
        "#e67e22",
        "#2ecc71",
        "#f2e335",
        "#ef4a92",
      ];
      let randomcolor;
      let square_number = 300;
      let container = document.getElementById("container");
      let box;

      let interval;

      const color = (e) => {
        const random = randomcolors();
        console.log(random, e.target);

        e.target.style.backgroundColor = random;
      };
      for (let i = 0; i < square_number; i++) {
        box = document.createElement("div");
        box.classList.add("square");

        container.appendChild(box);
      }
      document.querySelectorAll(".square").forEach((square) => {
        square.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
          color(this);
        });
      });

     

      // color-selection
      const randomcolors = () => {
        return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];
      };
```

I am calling `color(e)` function but on callig `color(e)` function i get e.target value undefined but when i called color function beside mouseover ,color(e)  function work explain me why this happened

Comment: Arrow functions do not have their own `this` binding, so when you pass this to the color function, it is `undefined`. To make this work; you should use a regular function and pass the event object to the color function.

Comment: `square.addEventListener("mouseover", e => color(e) );`

Comment: Thinking on it a bit more, it could be shortened to `square.addEventListener("mouseover", color);`

Comment: the this of Arrow functions is global object , not always undefined.